# How can i stop all audio playing using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-mobile, kineticjs

I'm updating a div in a page using jquery mobile in order to play some animations.

The animations also play sound through use of `document.createElement('audio');`

My problem is, when I update the page to another animation, the old sound keeps playing.

Sorry, this is my first question and if it seems like im not phrasing it properly I apologise.

Here is my code..

Here is the code of the animation to be loaded into the #animation div

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="scripts/kinetic-v4.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    /*BABY SCENE*/
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 578,
        height: 400
    });
    var babyLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var backLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();


    var imageObj = new Image();
    var backObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {
    var baby = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: stage.getWidth() / 2 -100 ,
      y: stage.getHeight() / 2 -100,
      image: imageObj,
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      opacity: 0.0
    });

    var background = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      image: backObj,
      width: 578,
      height: 400,
      opacity: 0.0
    });

    // add the shape to the layer
    babyLayer.add(baby);
    backLayer.add(background);

    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(babyLayer);
    stage.add(backLayer);
    babyLayer.moveToTop();
    babyLayer.draw();

    /*ANIMATION TIMELINE
     * 
     * FIRST EVENT: FADE IN BABY
     * SECOND EVENT: BABY TRANSITION
     * THIRD EVENT: FADE IN BACKGROUND
     */

    /*1) Fade in Baby*/
    setTimeout(function() {
        baby.transitionTo({
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 1
    });
    }, 200);

    setTimeout(function() {
    /*JQuery Baby Speech*/
       $(document).ready(function() {
        var babySpeech = document.createElement('audio');
        babySpeech.setAttribute('src', '../Animations/sounds/babyspeech.mp3');
        babySpeech.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
        //audioElement.load()
        $.get();
        babySpeech.addEventListener("load", function() {
        babySpeech.play();
        }, true);
    });
    }, 800);

    /*2) Baby Transition*/
    setTimeout(function() {
        baby.transitionTo({
        x: 140,
        y: stage.getHeight() / 2 + 59,
        width: 106,
        height: 118,
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 3
    });
    }, 3000);

    setTimeout(function() {
    /*JQuery Baby Giggle*/
       $(document).ready(function() {
        var baby = document.createElement('audio');
        baby.setAttribute('src', '../Animations/sounds/baby.mp3');
        baby.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
        //audioElement.load()
        $.get();
        baby.addEventListener("load", function() {
        baby.play();
        }, true);
    });
    }, 3000);

    /*3) Fade in Background*/
    setTimeout(function() {
        background.transitionTo({
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 3
    });
    }, 3200);

    setTimeout(function() {
    /*Second JQuery Baby Speech*/
       $(document).ready(function() {
        var babySpeech = document.createElement('audio');
        babySpeech.setAttribute('src', '../Animations/sounds/babyspeech.mp3');
        babySpeech.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
        //audioElement.load()
        $.get();
        babySpeech.addEventListener("load", function() {
        babySpeech.play();
        }, true);
    });
    }, 8700);


  };
  imageObj.src = '../Animations/images/baby.png';
  backObj.src = '../Animations/images/background/babyroom.jpg';

</script>
```

Here is the main page code. It gets the filename of the animation page to be loaded into #animation from an array when you click the next button.

```
<div id="nav" data-role="content" style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; position: relative; top:450px">
    <a href="#animation" data-role="button" data-inline="true" id ="back">Back</a>
    <a href="#animation" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" id="next">Next</a>
    <script>
        var count=0;
        var link_array = ['baby', 'bed', 'book', 'cat', 'chair', 'daddy', 'dog', 'mummy', 'shoe', 'teddy'];
        $("#next").click(function(e) {
            if(count!==9)
            { 
                $('audio').stop();
                count+=1;
            }
            $('#animation1wl').load('../Animations/' + link_array[count] + '.html');
            $('#animation1wl').trigger('create');
        }); 
        $("#back").click(function(e) {
            if(count !==0)
            {
                count-=1;
            }
            $('#animation1wl').load('../Animations/' + link_array[count] + '.html');
            $('#animation1wl').trigger('create');
        }); 
    </script>
</div>

<div id="animation" data-role="content" style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left">Problem Loading Resource LNW</div>
```

When I click the forward or back buttons, I want the audio from the previous animation loaded into #animation to stop playing..

Here is the code rendered inside #animation

```
<div id="animation1wl" data-role="content" style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left" class="ui-content" role="main">


    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>


    <div id="container"><div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 578px; height: 400px;" class="kineticjs-content"><canvas width="578" style="width: 578px; height: 400px; position: absolute;" height="400"></canvas><canvas width="578" style="width: 578px; height: 400px; position: absolute;" height="400"></canvas></div></div>
    <script src="scripts/kinetic-v4.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      /*BABY SCENE*/
      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 578,
        height: 400
      });
      var babyLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
      var backLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();


      var imageObj = new Image();
      var backObj = new Image();
      imageObj.onload = function() {
        var baby = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: stage.getWidth() / 2 -100 ,
          y: stage.getHeight() / 2 -100,
          image: imageObj,
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          opacity: 0.0
        });

        var background = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          image: backObj,
          width: 578,
          height: 400,
          opacity: 0.0
        });

        // add the shape to the layer
        babyLayer.add(baby);
        backLayer.add(background);

        // add the layer to the stage
        stage.add(babyLayer);
        stage.add(backLayer);
        babyLayer.moveToTop();
        babyLayer.draw();

        /*ANIMATION TIMELINE
         * 
         * FIRST EVENT: FADE IN BABY
         * SECOND EVENT: BABY TRANSITION
         * THIRD EVENT: FADE IN BACKGROUND
         */

        /*1) Fade in Baby*/
        setTimeout(function() {
            baby.transitionTo({
            opacity: 1,
            duration: 1
        });
        }, 200);

        setTimeout(function() {
        /*JQuery Baby Speech*/
           $(document).ready(function() {
            var babySpeech = document.createElement('audio');
            babySpeech.setAttribute('src', '../Animations/sounds/babyspeech.mp3');
            babySpeech.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
            //audioElement.load()
            $.get();
            babySpeech.addEventListener("load", function() {
            babySpeech.play();
            }, true);
        });
        }, 800);

        /*2) Baby Transition*/
        setTimeout(function() {
            baby.transitionTo({
            x: 140,
            y: stage.getHeight() / 2 + 59,
            width: 106,
            height: 118,
            opacity: 1,
            duration: 3
        });
        }, 3000);

        setTimeout(function() {
        /*JQuery Baby Giggle*/
           $(document).ready(function() {
            var baby = document.createElement('audio');
            baby.setAttribute('src', '../Animations/sounds/baby.mp3');
            baby.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
            //audioElement.load()
            $.get();
            baby.addEventListener("load", function() {
            baby.play();
            }, true);
        });
        }, 3000);

        /*3) Fade in Background*/
        setTimeout(function() {
            background.transitionTo({
            opacity: 1,
            duration: 3
        });
        }, 3200);

        setTimeout(function() {
        /*Second JQuery Baby Speech*/
           $(document).ready(function() {
            var babySpeech = document.createElement('audio');
            babySpeech.setAttribute('src', '../Animations/sounds/babyspeech.mp3');
            babySpeech.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
            //audioElement.load()
            $.get();
            babySpeech.addEventListener("load", function() {
            babySpeech.play();
            }, true);
        });
        }, 8700);

        console.log($('animation1wl').find('audio')[0]);

      };
      imageObj.src = '../Animations/images/baby.png';
      backObj.src = '../Animations/images/background/babyroom.jpg';

    </script>

</div>
```

Any help would be great..

Thanks very much.

Comment: when leaving a page, use this `$(document).on('pagebeforehide', '#pageID', function() { //stop audio });` or on showing a page `$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#pageID', function() { //stop audio });`

Comment: Thanks for this, but I tried to insert this code block and it doesnt stop the audio as I cilick next.  Where should I be inserting it?  And how do I stop the audio?  pologies again, i'm very new to all this..

Comment: When click next, do you go to another page, or stay in the same page?

Comment: Just update one portion of the page div with another page

Comment: `.stop()` in jQuery stops animation, while `.pause()` stops audio. Try `.pause()` instead.

Comment: That doesn't do it either sorry :( Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'pause' $('audio').pause();

Comment: Ok, try `$('audio')[0].pause()` and post the markup of `#animation` after loading it.

Comment: Animation is just a DIV <div id="animation" data-role="content" style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left">Problem Loading Resource LNW</div> ('audio')[0].pause() gives the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'pause' of undefined (11:42:03:926 | error, javascript)
    at  (public_html/Main/index.html:269:39)
    at jQuery.event.dispatch (public_html/Main/splitviewSrc/jquery-1.7.1.js:3256:16)
    at elemData.handle.eventHandle (public_html/Main/splitviewSrc/jquery-1.7.1.js:2875:33)

Comment: you need to fetch the name of the audio file and `.pause()`. `$('audio')` returns an array.

Comment: I've updated my code above.

Comment: add this and show me what you get if `console.log($('animation').find('audio')[0]);`.

Comment: undefined (12:06:51:098)
  at public_html/Main/index.html:193 The audio is created in the other file baby.html, but loaded into the div in the main file.

Comment: hmmmm, what's the structure of `../Animations/bird.html` html code.

Comment: bird? Do you mean Baby? I've added the code that creates the audio in baby.html to the above code example.

Comment: lol any, i thought there was a bird, yea baby or book. all have the same structure right?

Comment: Yes they all have the lines var audio = document.createElement('audio'); as above

Comment: ok but what is insde baby.html what's the code.

Comment: added it above, i'm actually pretty embarrassed adding my code as i'm a total newbie. Sorry if it is awful!  Thanks for helping me I appreciate it.

Comment: You shouldn't be embarrassed at all. if you're Chrome, open your page and then hit 'f12' to open DevTools window. on that window, go to Elements and copy '#animation' rendered code.

Comment: the code rendered in animation is listed above.  When I go into the rendered code, it lists the code verbatim as above.

Comment: I've added it to the end of the example code above anyway.

Comment: put this `<script>console.log($('animation1wl').find('audio')[0]);</script>` in the main page. tell me what your get.

Comment: undefined (15:29:33:889)
  at public_html/Main/index.html:132
undefined (15:29:34:146)

Comment: ok try `$('#animation1wl audio').pause()` instead of `$('audio').stop().`

Comment: ncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'pause' (15:38:12:692 | error, javascript)
    at  (public_html/Main/index.html:147:50)

Comment: send me an email to omarmt[at]gmail.com i need to see the rendered code not the source.

Comment: Do you want me to send you the files?

Comment: Sure, if you dont mind.

Comment: Id love to send you the files, but I have another problem.  This code doesnt work outside of netbeans because of the way chrome's security settings are set up (apparently).  I can't link to a local file inside of my project, only to an external URL or the content in the #animation div wont load... i'll send you it anyway...

Comment: a live link to your project is enough if applicable.

Comment: Its not going live, I have to run it in a webview as part of an android app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ihad to rewrite the code but, I got this working in the end by loading the animation in its entirety when you click on the next button rather than just updating a single div.

It's a workaround but at least its working now.

Thanks to Omar who helped a lot with this problem.

Comment: It would be nice if you'd edit the initial question to include the implementation of your solution.

Answer (score 33):

You can do something like this:

```
$('audio').each(function(){
    this.pause(); // Stop playing
    this.currentTime = 0; // Reset time
});
```

Comment: I was changing my answer in the meanwhile. So it was not up to date yet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I still can't get it to work.  Where do I insert this code?  I put it into the #next block but still the audio plays when I click the next animation.

Comment: Be aware that this might throw an error if the the audio element wasn't initialized yet (i.e. no playhead due to mobile preloading policies). Wrap it in a try cath and you should be fine.

Comment: How do you add code to comments? >-<! I've tried inserting this code after $("#next").click(function(e) { but it doesnt do anything.  The audio from the previous animation still plays.

Comment: No I mean how to I make code in these comments appear as you do in the grey styled blocks.

Comment: If you only have one initialised audio you can do: 
$('audio')[0].pause();