# Revolution Slider YouTube video mute delayed

Tags: wordpress, youtube, youtube-iframe-api, revolution-slider

I have a WP site with Revolution Slider autoplaying a full screen YouTube video on the homepage.

I selected the mute option for the video in the settings, however the audio plays for 1 second on load! It literally sounds like a glitch.

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Maybe this it's not your solution but you can have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930328/how-can-i-stop-all-audio-playing-using-jquery

Comment: Or maybe you can add a pre-load page. Or try to move the jQuery of the plug-in the the header, just the part you need, in the way it's read before load all the page.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you get the solution for this??

Comment: I have the same issue, the mute is delayed

Answer (score -2):

```
hd=1&vq=hd720&wmode=opaque&showinfo=0&rel=0&mute=1;
```

add `&mute=1` into the youtube arguments section in revolution slider, above is an example of youtube arguments I have used.