# How to Use audio tag and play source from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I found This to use but how can i make the id to tally with each music query from the database

```js
var myAudio = document.getElementById("myfile");

function togglePlay() {
  return myAudio.paused ? myAudio.play() : myAudio.pause();
};
```

```html
<audio id="myfile" src="/musicfile/{{$ebeat->beat}}" preload="auto"></audio>
<a onClick="togglePlay()">{{$ebeat->title}}</a>
```

Comment: How are the audio files stored in the database? You need to find a method of serving them as valid binary files from the server - which would seem to be the problem you need to fix before writing any JS code.

Comment: The audio files were stored as strings and moved to a folder. The issue I am having is with the audio id. only the first music played even when I I clicked on others.@RoryMcCrossan

Comment: So you have multiple `audio` elements with the same `id`? If so, that's your problem. Could you edit your question to show a HTML sample with how your code is organised with regards to multiple `audio` and `a` elements

Comment: Even when i try to replace the audio with the various unique id of each music file from database<audio id="{{$ebeat->id}}" src="/musicfile/{{$ebeat->beat}}" preload="auto"></audio>
<a onClick="togglePlay()">{{$ebeat->title}}</a> @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: How are you targeting the audio elements in the `togglePlay()` function?

Comment: Via audio id like this var myAudio = document.getElementById("myfile"); @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: I added an answer for you

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're repeating the same pair of elements throughout the DOM it would make more sense to make the code generic. To do that use DOM traversal to get the previous sibling `audio` element to the clicked `a` element. To do that you can use the `previousSibling` from the reference to the clicked element:

```
function togglePlay(el) {
  var audio = this.previousSibling;
  return audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
};
```

```html
<audio id="myfile" src="/musicfile/{{$ebeat->beat}}" preload="auto"></audio>
<a onClick="togglePlay(this)">{{$ebeat->title}}</a>
```

Alternatively, as you tagged the question with jQuery, you can use `prev()`, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('a.togglePlay').click(function(e) {
    var audio = $(this).prev()[0];
    return audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
  });
});
```

```html
<audio id="myfile" src="/musicfile/{{$ebeat->beat}}" preload="auto"></audio>
<a href="#" class="togglePlay">{{$ebeat->title}}</a>
```

Comment: It work but the previous did not stop while the next played they were both playing whereas I want the previous to stop playing onchange @Rory McCrossan

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930328/how-can-i-stop-all-audio-playing-using-jquery

Comment: Thanks @Rory McCrossan but how can I implement this $('audio').each(function(){
    this.pause(); // Stop playing
    this.currentTime = 0; // Reset time
});  with my current situation of this  $(function() {
  $('a.togglePlay').click(function(e) {
    var audio = $(this).prev()[0];
    return audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
  });
});